# Loading sub sections with a titles

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I’m doing a few left_joins trying to preload some nested associations. I have `sections`, that have `sub_sections`, and I want to get all `sub_sections` that have a title (as opposed to sub_sections with no title). When I add this line, the whole query returns nil, but when I remove it, I get everything (including the sub_sections with no titles). `where: not is_nil(sub2.title)`.

I'm having a hard time finding what I'm doing wrong here? I feel like I should be getting the results with this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

````
from a in Article,
  left_join: s in assoc(a, :sections),
  left_join: d in assoc(s, :definitions),
  left_join: sub in assoc(d, :sub_sections),
  left_join: sub2 in assoc(sub, :sub_sections),
  where: a.id == ^id,
  where: not is_nil(sub2.title),
  preload: [sections: {s, [definitions: {d, [sub_sections: {sub, sub_sections: sub2}]}]}]```
````

Comment: Why do you join ```sub_sections``` two times? You need just the first, I guess?

Comment: It’s a self-referential association. Each sub_section can have many sub_sections.

Comment: So the query is looking for "subsubsections" without a title in a specified article and any "section", "definition" or "subsection" without a child.. I am not sure what you are expecting. It sounds more like every "subsection", no matter how "deep" (so also "subsubsection"s, "subsubsubsection"s etc.), that has no title, for a specified article. Is this correct? Perhaps you can give some example data and your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the condition `not is_nil(sub2.title)` onto the respective `join`, not onto the whole query. Somewhat like the below should work.

```
subs = from sub in SubSection, where: not is_nil(sub.title)

from a in Article,
  left_join: s in assoc(a, :sections),
  left_join: d in assoc(s, :definitions),
  left_join: sub in assoc(d, :sub_sections),
  left_join: sub2 in ^subs, on: sub2.parent == sub.id,
  where: a.id == ^id,
  preload: [sections: {
    s, [definitions:
     {d, [sub_sections: {sub, sub_sections: sub2}]}]}]
```

Comment: That was it! Makes a lot of sense too. Thanks so much for answering!  One thing to note for folks who might be reading this, make sure you add the `^` before subs to tell ecto that it's a variable ```left_join: sub2 in ^subs, on: sub2.parent == sub.id```

Comment: Welcome. I fixed a pin in the answer.